# Change the height of a column line

Tags: html, css

So i was playing around with CSS and i found a way to make lines appear beetween my navigation tabs.

So for example it would be

```
Home | About etc etc
```

I wanted to know how i would change the size of the "|"

The way i have got it coded is

```
li+li { 
    border-left: 1px solid  #00FFFF;
}
```

I have tried height etc but it does nothing to change the size of the actual line. It just stays the same. So anyway which changes the actual height would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pseudo element `:before` or `:after` to create the line.

```css
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav li + li:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  padding-left: 8px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  height: 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should surround the list elements with a `div` in the actual HTML and give that a `border-left: 1px solid  #00FFFF;` with CSS.

Comment: That is true but the way i do it , it means on the last nav tab the line wont appear, so it will always appear until the last tab

Answer (score 0):

The height on the border should work.

## Examples

Compare the two nav listed below and check the height on the border.

```
<nav>
  <li class="navlinks">Home</li>
  <li class="navlinks">About</li>
  <li class="navlinks">Contact</li>
</nav>
<br>
<br>
<nav>
  <li class="navlinks2">Home</li>
  <li class="navlinks2">About</li>
  <li class="navlinks2">Contact</li>
</nav>


nav{
  height:50px;
  background-color: #9e9e9e;
  width:100%;
}

li{
  position:relative;
  display: block;
  float:left;
  padding:15px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.navlinks{
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  height: 5px;
}


.navlinks2{
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  height: 30px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Bespinoza10/pen/LGeyXe

```css
nav{
  height:50px;
  background-color: #9e9e9e;
  width:100%;
}

li{
  position:relative;
  display: block;
  float:left;
  padding:15px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.navlinks{
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  height: 5px;
}


.navlinks2{
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <li class="navlinks">Home</li>
  <li class="navlinks">About</li>
  <li class="navlinks">Contact</li>
</nav>
<br>
<br>
<nav>
  <li class="navlinks2">Home</li>
  <li class="navlinks2">About</li>
  <li class="navlinks2">Contact</li>
</nav>
```

#### I put the example on here just run the script and also on codepen.io